# Different speed of quantreg lib on win7 and linux mint

Tags: r, performance, lapack, f2c, quantreg

I'm using `quantreg` library on both win7 64bit and linux Mint Maya 64bit and I realised big speed difference.

I'm using Frisch-Newton method written in Fortran and I was mesuring speed only of the .Fortran() calling.

I'm analyzing vector with length of 1600.

On windows it takes about 2.5 seconds, on Linux it takes about 22 seconds. And I really don't understand why..

After this I tried to translate Fortran code into C code by F2C and compile it into dynamic library with clapack functions. I was calling this function by .C() and I measured the time efficiency again:

On windows it took 8 seconds and on Linux 22.5 seconds. I'm really confused.

All has been done on I7-3770, 16GB RAM.

Can somebody explain to me why it does not work?

Here is the code:

Fortran code:

```
C Output from Public domain Ratfor, version 1.0
  subroutine rqfnb(n,p,a,y,rhs,d,u,beta,eps,wn,wp,nit,info)
  integer n,p,info,nit(3)
  double precision a(p,n),y(n),rhs(p),d(n),u(n),wn(n,9),wp(p,p+3)
  double precision one,beta,eps
  parameter( one = 1.0d0)
  call lpfnb(n,p,a,y,rhs,d,u,beta,eps,wn(1,1),wn(1,2), wp(1,1),wn(1,
 *3),wn(1,4),wn(1,5),wn(1,6), wp(1,2),wn(1,7),wn(1,8),wn(1,9),wp(1,3
 *),wp(1,4),nit,info)
  return
  end
  subroutine lpfnb(n,p,a,c,b,d,u,beta,eps,x,s,y,z,w, dx,ds,dy,dz,dw,
 *dr,rhs,ada,nit,info)
  integer n,p,pp,i,info,nit(3),maxit
  double precision a(p,n),c(n),b(p)
  double precision zero,one,mone,big,ddot,dmax1,dmin1,dxdz,dsdw
  double precision deltap,deltad,beta,eps,mu,gap,g
  double precision x(n),u(n),s(n),y(p),z(n),w(n),d(n),rhs(p),ada(p,p
 *)
  double precision dx(n),ds(n),dy(p),dz(n),dw(n),dr(n)
  parameter( zero = 0.0d0)
  parameter( one = 1.0d0)
  parameter( mone = -1.0d0)
  parameter( big = 1.0d+20)
  parameter( maxit = 50)
  nit(1)=0
  nit(2)=0
  nit(3)=n
  pp=p*p
  call dgemv('N',p,n,one,a,p,c,1,zero,y,1)
  do23000 i=1,n
  d(i)=one
23000 continue
23001 continue
      call stepy(n,p,a,d,y,ada,info)
      if(info .ne. 0)then
      return
      endif
      call dcopy(n,c,1,s,1)
      call dgemv('T',p,n,mone,a,p,y,1,one,s,1)
      do23004 i=1,n
      if(dabs(s(i)).lt.eps)then
      z(i)=dmax1(s(i), zero) + eps
      w(i)=dmax1(-s(i),zero) + eps
      else
      z(i)=dmax1(s(i), zero)
      w(i)=dmax1(-s(i),zero)
      endif
      s(i)=u(i)-x(i)
23004 continue
23005 continue
      gap = ddot(n,z,1,x,1)+ddot(n,w,1,s,1)
23008 if(gap .gt. eps .and. nit(1).lt.maxit)then
      nit(1)=nit(1)+1
      do23010 i = 1,n
      d(i) = one/(z(i)/x(i) + w(i)/s(i))
      ds(i)=z(i)-w(i)
      dz(i)=d(i)*ds(i)
23010 continue
23011 continue
      call dcopy(p,b,1,dy,1)
      call dgemv('N',p,n,mone,a,p,x,1,one,dy,1)
      call dgemv('N',p,n,one,a,p,dz,1,one,dy,1)
      call dcopy(p,dy,1,rhs,1)
      call stepy(n,p,a,d,dy,ada,info)
      if(info .ne. 0)then
      return
      endif
      call dgemv('T',p,n,one,a,p,dy,1,mone,ds,1)
      deltap=big
      deltad=big
      do23014 i=1,n
      dx(i)=d(i)*ds(i)
      ds(i)=-dx(i)
      dz(i)=-z(i)*(dx(i)/x(i) + one)
      dw(i)=-w(i)*(ds(i)/s(i) + one)
      if(dx(i).lt.0)then
      deltap=dmin1(deltap,-x(i)/dx(i))
      endif
      if(ds(i).lt.0)then
      deltap=dmin1(deltap,-s(i)/ds(i))
      endif
      if(dz(i).lt.0)then
      deltad=dmin1(deltad,-z(i)/dz(i))
      endif
      if(dw(i).lt.0)then
      deltad=dmin1(deltad,-w(i)/dw(i))
      endif
23014 continue
23015 continue
      deltap=dmin1(beta*deltap,one)
      deltad=dmin1(beta*deltad,one)
      if(min(deltap,deltad) .lt. one)then
      nit(2)=nit(2)+1
      mu = ddot(n,x,1,z,1)+ddot(n,s,1,w,1)
      g = mu + deltap*ddot(n,dx,1,z,1)+ deltad*ddot(n,dz,1,x,1) + deltap
     **deltad*ddot(n,dz,1,dx,1)+ deltap*ddot(n,ds,1,w,1)+ deltad*ddot(n,
     *dw,1,s,1) + deltap*deltad*ddot(n,ds,1,dw,1)
      mu = mu * ((g/mu)**3) /dfloat(2*n)
      do23026 i=1,n
      dr(i)=d(i)*(mu*(1/s(i)-1/x(i))+ dx(i)*dz(i)/x(i)-ds(i)*dw(i)/s(i))
23026 continue
23027 continue
      call dswap(p,rhs,1,dy,1)
      call dgemv('N',p,n,one,a,p,dr,1,one,dy,1)
      call dpotrs('U',p,1,ada,p,dy,p,info)
      call dgemv('T',p,n,one,a,p,dy,1,zero,u,1)
      deltap=big
      deltad=big
      do23028 i=1,n
      dxdz = dx(i)*dz(i)
      dsdw = ds(i)*dw(i)
      dx(i)= d(i)*(u(i)-z(i)+w(i))-dr(i)
      ds(i)= -dx(i)
      dz(i)= -z(i)+(mu - z(i)*dx(i) - dxdz)/x(i)
      dw(i)= -w(i)+(mu - w(i)*ds(i) - dsdw)/s(i)
      if(dx(i).lt.0)then
      deltap=dmin1(deltap,-x(i)/dx(i))
      endif
      if(ds(i).lt.0)then
      deltap=dmin1(deltap,-s(i)/ds(i))
      endif
      if(dz(i).lt.0)then
      deltad=dmin1(deltad,-z(i)/dz(i))
      endif
      if(dw(i).lt.0)then
      deltad=dmin1(deltad,-w(i)/dw(i))
      endif
23028 continue
23029 continue
      deltap=dmin1(beta*deltap,one)
      deltad=dmin1(beta*deltad,one)
      endif
      call daxpy(n,deltap,dx,1,x,1)
      call daxpy(n,deltap,ds,1,s,1)
      call daxpy(p,deltad,dy,1,y,1)
      call daxpy(n,deltad,dz,1,z,1)
      call daxpy(n,deltad,dw,1,w,1)
      gap = ddot(n,z,1,x,1)+ddot(n,w,1,s,1)
      goto 23008
      endif
23009 continue
      call daxpy(n,mone,w,1,z,1)
      call dswap(n,z,1,x,1)
      return
      end
      subroutine stepy(n,p,a,d,b,ada,info)
      integer n,p,pp,i,info
      double precision a(p,n),b(p),d(n),ada(p,p),zero
      parameter( zero = 0.0d0)
      pp=p*p
      do23038 j=1,p
      do23040 k=1,p
      ada(j,k)=zero
23040 continue
23041 continue
23038 continue
23039 continue
      do23042 i=1,n
      call dsyr('U',p,d(i),a(1,i),1,ada,p)
23042 continue
23043 continue
      call dposv('U',p,1,ada,p,b,p,info)
      return
      end
```

C code:

```
    /* rqfnb.f -- translated by f2c (version 20090411).
   You must link the resulting object file with libf2c:
    on Microsoft Windows system, link with libf2c.lib;
    on Linux or Unix systems, link with .../path/to/libf2c.a -lm
    or, if you install libf2c.a in a standard place, with -lf2c -lm
    -- in that order, at the end of the command line, as in
        cc *.o -lf2c -lm
    Source for libf2c is in /netlib/f2c/libf2c.zip, e.g.,

        http://www.netlib.org/f2c/libf2c.zip
*/

#include "f2c.h"
#include "clapack.h"


/* Table of constant values */

static doublereal c_b4 = 1.;
static integer c__1 = 1;
static doublereal c_b6 = 0.;
static doublereal c_b13 = -1.;

/* Output from Public domain Ratfor, version 1.0 */
/* Subroutine */ int rqfnb_(integer *n, integer *p, doublereal *a, doublereal 
    *y, doublereal *rhs, doublereal *d__, doublereal *u, doublereal *beta,
     doublereal *eps, doublereal *wn, doublereal *wp, integer *nit, 
    integer *info)
{
    /* System generated locals */
    integer a_dim1, a_offset, wn_dim1, wn_offset, wp_dim1, wp_offset;

    /* Local variables */
    extern /* Subroutine */ int lpfnb_(integer *, integer *, doublereal *, 
        doublereal *, doublereal *, doublereal *, doublereal *, 
        doublereal *, doublereal *, doublereal *, doublereal *, 
        doublereal *, doublereal *, doublereal *, doublereal *, 
        doublereal *, doublereal *, doublereal *, doublereal *, 
        doublereal *, doublereal *, doublereal *, integer *, integer *);

    /* Parameter adjustments */
    wn_dim1 = *n;
    wn_offset = 1 + wn_dim1;
    wn -= wn_offset;
    --u;
    --d__;
    --y;
    wp_dim1 = *p;
    wp_offset = 1 + wp_dim1;
    wp -= wp_offset;
    --rhs;
    a_dim1 = *p;
    a_offset = 1 + a_dim1;
    a -= a_offset;
    --nit;

    /* Function Body */
    lpfnb_(n, p, &a[a_offset], &y[1], &rhs[1], &d__[1], &u[1], beta, eps, &wn[
        wn_dim1 + 1], &wn[(wn_dim1 << 1) + 1], &wp[wp_dim1 + 1], &wn[
        wn_dim1 * 3 + 1], &wn[(wn_dim1 << 2) + 1], &wn[wn_dim1 * 5 + 1], &
        wn[wn_dim1 * 6 + 1], &wp[(wp_dim1 << 1) + 1], &wn[wn_dim1 * 7 + 1]
        , &wn[(wn_dim1 << 3) + 1], &wn[wn_dim1 * 9 + 1], &wp[wp_dim1 * 3 
        + 1], &wp[(wp_dim1 << 2) + 1], &nit[1], info);
    return 0;
} /* rqfnb_ */

/* Subroutine */ int lpfnb_(integer *n, integer *p, doublereal *a, doublereal 
    *c__, doublereal *b, doublereal *d__, doublereal *u, doublereal *beta,
     doublereal *eps, doublereal *x, doublereal *s, doublereal *y, 
    doublereal *z__, doublereal *w, doublereal *dx, doublereal *ds, 
    doublereal *dy, doublereal *dz, doublereal *dw, doublereal *dr, 
    doublereal *rhs, doublereal *ada, integer *nit, integer *info)
{
    /* System generated locals */
    integer a_dim1, a_offset, ada_dim1, ada_offset, i__1;
    doublereal d__1, d__2;

    /* Local variables */
    static doublereal g;
    static integer i__;
    static doublereal mu, gap;
    extern doublereal ddot_(integer *, doublereal *, integer *, doublereal *, 
        integer *);
    static doublereal dsdw, dxdz;


    extern /* Subroutine */ int stepy_(integer *, integer *, doublereal *, doublereal *, doublereal *, doublereal *, integer *);
    static doublereal deltad, deltap;


    /* Parameter adjustments */
    --dr;
    --dw;
    --dz;
    --ds;
    --dx;
    --w;
    --z__;
    --s;
    --x;
    --u;
    --d__;
    --c__;
    ada_dim1 = *p;
    ada_offset = 1 + ada_dim1;
    ada -= ada_offset;
    --rhs;
    --dy;
    --y;
    --b;
    a_dim1 = *p;
    a_offset = 1 + a_dim1;
    a -= a_offset;
    --nit;

    /* Function Body */
    nit[1] = 0;
    nit[2] = 0;
    nit[3] = *n;

    dgemv_("N", p, n, &c_b4, &a[a_offset], p, &c__[1], &c__1, &c_b6, &y[1], &c__1);     

    i__1 = *n;
    for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    d__[i__] = 1.;
/* L23000: */
    }
/* L23001: */
    stepy_(n, p, &a[a_offset], &d__[1], &y[1], &ada[ada_offset], info);
    if (*info != 0) {
    return 0;
    }
    dcopy_(n, &c__[1], &c__1, &s[1], &c__1);
    dgemv_("T", p, n, &c_b13, &a[a_offset], p, &y[1], &c__1, &c_b4, &s[1], &c__1);      

    i__1 = *n;
    for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    if ((d__1 = s[i__], abs(d__1)) < *eps) {
/* Computing MAX */
        d__1 = s[i__];
        z__[i__] = max(d__1,0.) + *eps;
/* Computing MAX */
        d__1 = -s[i__];
        w[i__] = max(d__1,0.) + *eps;
    } else {
/* Computing MAX */
        d__1 = s[i__];
        z__[i__] = max(d__1,0.);
/* Computing MAX */
        d__1 = -s[i__];
        w[i__] = max(d__1,0.);
    }
    s[i__] = u[i__] - x[i__];
/* L23004: */
    }
/* L23005: */
    gap = ddot_(n, &z__[1], &c__1, &x[1], &c__1) + ddot_(n, &w[1], &c__1, &s[
        1], &c__1);
L23008:
    if (gap > *eps && nit[1] < 50) {
    ++nit[1];
    i__1 = *n;
    for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
        d__[i__] = 1. / (z__[i__] / x[i__] + w[i__] / s[i__]);
        ds[i__] = z__[i__] - w[i__];
        dz[i__] = d__[i__] * ds[i__];
/* L23010: */
    }
/* L23011: */
    dcopy_(p, &b[1], &c__1, &dy[1], &c__1);
    dgemv_("N", p, n, &c_b13, &a[a_offset], p, &x[1], &c__1, &c_b4, &dy[1], &c__1);     

    dgemv_("N", p, n, &c_b4, &a[a_offset], p, &dz[1], &c__1, &c_b4, &dy[1], &c__1);     

    dcopy_(p, &dy[1], &c__1, &rhs[1], &c__1);
    stepy_(n, p, &a[a_offset], &d__[1], &dy[1], &ada[ada_offset], info);
    if (*info != 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    dgemv_("T", p, n, &c_b4, &a[a_offset], p, &dy[1], &c__1, &c_b13, &ds[1], &c__1);        

    deltap = 1e20;
    deltad = 1e20;
    i__1 = *n;
    for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
        dx[i__] = d__[i__] * ds[i__];
        ds[i__] = -dx[i__];
        dz[i__] = -z__[i__] * (dx[i__] / x[i__] + 1.);
        dw[i__] = -w[i__] * (ds[i__] / s[i__] + 1.);
        if (dx[i__] < 0.) {
/* Computing MIN */
        d__1 = deltap, d__2 = -x[i__] / dx[i__];
        deltap = min(d__1,d__2);
        }
        if (ds[i__] < 0.) {
/* Computing MIN */
        d__1 = deltap, d__2 = -s[i__] / ds[i__];
        deltap = min(d__1,d__2);
        }
        if (dz[i__] < 0.) {
/* Computing MIN */
        d__1 = deltad, d__2 = -z__[i__] / dz[i__];
        deltad = min(d__1,d__2);
        }
        if (dw[i__] < 0.) {
/* Computing MIN */
        d__1 = deltad, d__2 = -w[i__] / dw[i__];
        deltad = min(d__1,d__2);
        }
/* L23014: */
    }
/* L23015: */
/* Computing MIN */
    d__1 = *beta * deltap;
    deltap = min(d__1,1.);
/* Computing MIN */
    d__1 = *beta * deltad;
    deltad = min(d__1,1.);
    if (min(deltap,deltad) < 1.) {
        ++nit[2];
        mu = ddot_(n, &x[1], &c__1, &z__[1], &c__1) + ddot_(n, &s[1], &
            c__1, &w[1], &c__1);
        g = mu + deltap * ddot_(n, &dx[1], &c__1, &z__[1], &c__1) + 
            deltad * ddot_(n, &dz[1], &c__1, &x[1], &c__1) + deltap * 
            deltad * ddot_(n, &dz[1], &c__1, &dx[1], &c__1) + deltap *
             ddot_(n, &ds[1], &c__1, &w[1], &c__1) + deltad * ddot_(n,
             &dw[1], &c__1, &s[1], &c__1) + deltap * deltad * ddot_(n,
             &ds[1], &c__1, &dw[1], &c__1);
/* Computing 3rd power */
        d__1 = g / mu;
        mu = mu * (d__1 * (d__1 * d__1)) / (doublereal) (*n << 1);
        i__1 = *n;
        for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
        dr[i__] = d__[i__] * (mu * (1 / s[i__] - 1 / x[i__]) + dx[i__]
             * dz[i__] / x[i__] - ds[i__] * dw[i__] / s[i__]);
/* L23026: */
        }
/* L23027: */
        dswap_(p, &rhs[1], &c__1, &dy[1], &c__1);
    dgemv_("N", p, n, &c_b4, &a[a_offset], p, &dr[1], &c__1, &c_b4, &dy[1], &c__1);
    dpotrs_("U", p, &c__1, &ada[ada_offset], p, &dy[1], p, info);           
    dgemv_("T", p, n, &c_b4, &a[a_offset], p, &dy[1], &c__1, &c_b6, &u[1], &c__1);          
        deltap = 1e20;
        deltad = 1e20;
        i__1 = *n;
        for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
        dxdz = dx[i__] * dz[i__];
        dsdw = ds[i__] * dw[i__];
        dx[i__] = d__[i__] * (u[i__] - z__[i__] + w[i__]) - dr[i__];
        ds[i__] = -dx[i__];
        dz[i__] = -z__[i__] + (mu - z__[i__] * dx[i__] - dxdz) / x[
            i__];
        dw[i__] = -w[i__] + (mu - w[i__] * ds[i__] - dsdw) / s[i__];
        if (dx[i__] < 0.) {
/* Computing MIN */
            d__1 = deltap, d__2 = -x[i__] / dx[i__];
            deltap = min(d__1,d__2);
        }
        if (ds[i__] < 0.) {
/* Computing MIN */
            d__1 = deltap, d__2 = -s[i__] / ds[i__];
            deltap = min(d__1,d__2);
        }
        if (dz[i__] < 0.) {
/* Computing MIN */
            d__1 = deltad, d__2 = -z__[i__] / dz[i__];
            deltad = min(d__1,d__2);
        }
        if (dw[i__] < 0.) {
/* Computing MIN */
            d__1 = deltad, d__2 = -w[i__] / dw[i__];
            deltad = min(d__1,d__2);
        }
/* L23028: */
        }
/* L23029: */
/* Computing MIN */
        d__1 = *beta * deltap;
        deltap = min(d__1,1.);
/* Computing MIN */
        d__1 = *beta * deltad;
        deltad = min(d__1,1.);
    }
    daxpy_(n, &deltap, &dx[1], &c__1, &x[1], &c__1);
    daxpy_(n, &deltap, &ds[1], &c__1, &s[1], &c__1);
    daxpy_(p, &deltad, &dy[1], &c__1, &y[1], &c__1);
    daxpy_(n, &deltad, &dz[1], &c__1, &z__[1], &c__1);
    daxpy_(n, &deltad, &dw[1], &c__1, &w[1], &c__1);
    gap = ddot_(n, &z__[1], &c__1, &x[1], &c__1) + ddot_(n, &w[1], &c__1, 
        &s[1], &c__1);
    goto L23008;
    }
/* L23009: */
    daxpy_(n, &c_b13, &w[1], &c__1, &z__[1], &c__1);
    dswap_(n, &z__[1], &c__1, &x[1], &c__1);
    return 0;
} /* lpfnb_ */

/* Subroutine */ int stepy_(integer *n, integer *p, doublereal *a, doublereal 
    *d__, doublereal *b, doublereal *ada, integer *info)
{
    /* System generated locals */
    integer a_dim1, a_offset, ada_dim1, ada_offset, i__1, i__2;

    /* Local variables */
    static integer i__, j, k;       

    /* Parameter adjustments */
    --d__;
    ada_dim1 = *p;
    ada_offset = 1 + ada_dim1;
    ada -= ada_offset;
    --b;
    a_dim1 = *p;
    a_offset = 1 + a_dim1;
    a -= a_offset;

    /* Function Body */
    i__1 = *p;
    for (j = 1; j <= i__1; ++j) {
    i__2 = *p;
    for (k = 1; k <= i__2; ++k) {
        ada[j + k * ada_dim1] = 0.;
/* L23040: */
    }
/* L23041: */
/* L23038: */
    }
/* L23039: */
    i__1 = *n;
    for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    dsyr_("U", p, &d__[i__], &a[i__ * a_dim1 + 1], &c__1, &ada[ada_offset], p);     

/* L23042: */
    }
/* L23043: */
    dposv_("U", p, &c__1, &ada[ada_offset], p, &b[1], p, info);
    return 0;
} /* stepy_ */
```

Calling from R:

```
# C calling

y = rep(c(24,25,26,27,12,11,13,12),200)
lambda=2
tau = 0.50
m <- length(y)
E <- diag(m);
Dmat <- diff(E);
x <- rbind(E, lambda * Dmat)
y <- c(y, rep(0, m - 1))
beta = 0.99995
eps = 1e-06 
n <- length(y)
p <- ncol(x)
rhs <- (1 - tau) * apply(x, 2, sum)
d <- rep(1, n)
u <- rep(1, n)
wn <- rep(0, 10 * n)
wn[1:n] <- (1 - tau)

dyn.load("rqfnb.dll")
system.time(
.C("rqfnb_", as.integer(n), as.integer(p), a = as.double(t(as.matrix(x))), 
     c = as.double(-y), rhs = as.double(rhs), d = as.double(d), 
     as.double(u), beta = as.double(beta), eps = as.double(eps), 
     wn = as.double(wn), wp = double((p + 3) * p), it.count = integer(3),
    info = integer(1))
)
dyn.unload("rqfnb.dll")



# Fortran calling

library("quantreg")

y = rep(c(24,25,26,27,12,11,13,12),200)
lambda=2
tau = 0.50
m <- length(y)
E <- diag(m);
Dmat <- diff(E);
x <- rbind(E, lambda * Dmat)
y <- c(y, rep(0, m - 1))
beta = 0.99995
eps = 1e-06 
n <- length(y)
p <- ncol(x)
rhs <- (1 - tau) * apply(x, 2, sum)
d <- rep(1, n)
u <- rep(1, n)
wn <- rep(0, 10 * n)
wn[1:n] <- (1 - tau)

system.time(
.Fortran("rqfnb", as.integer(n), as.integer(p), a = as.double(t(as.matrix(x))), 
     c = as.double(-y), rhs = as.double(rhs), d = as.double(d), 
     as.double(u), beta = as.double(beta), eps = as.double(eps), 
     wn = as.double(wn), wp = double((p + 3) * p), it.count = integer(3),
    info = integer(1), PACKAGE = "quantreg")
)
```

Compiling of dynamic library:

```
R CMD SHLIB -L. -lf2c -lblas -llapack -lf2c -lblas -llapack rqfnb.c
```

Comment: You don't provide enough information, but it's probably because one system comes with a better BLAS by default.

Comment: do you think that BLAS is effecting original function (Fortran) too?
I will try to compile new BLAS on both systems with the same compiler and will see.

Comment: If the original function calls any linear algebra routines, yes.  It would be a lot easier for people to help if you told us what specific code you were using... which would be easily accomplished if you provided a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: I've uploaded the code, hope it's enough.

Comment: eek -- it's not exactly minimal ...

Comment: The `.Fortran` call takes ~5.6s on my 2.2Ghz Core2Duo, running Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit. The C code is going to be approximately the same, since it's calling the same underlying Fortran code in the BLAS. So, as I said previously, it probably takes longer on Mint Maya because it's using some inferior BLAS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling convention on x64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135871/calling-convention-on-x64)