# Calling convention on x64

Tags: compiler-construction, 64-bit, x86-64, calling-convention

I saw in several places that Microsoft calling conventions for `x64` platforms were narrowed down to just one: Caller cleans stack (`cdecl`), and parameters are passed in a combination of stack and registers (I am not going into the exact details here). I assume that if this is the calling convention of the OS, then probably all other compilers targeting Windows (e.g. mingw-w64) follow it, too.

Is this calling convention true also on other major platforms (`x64` Linux, etc.)? Or does Linux still use multiple calling conventions, or even just one but a different one? Do `GCC` or `Clang` allow for multiple calling conventions on `x64` Linux?

Comment: Those happy days are about to end.  Microsoft is adding the __vectorcall calling convention.  Up to six `__m128` values passed through SSE2 registers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just found the answer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86). Basically, Windows does it one way, everyone else does it another way, but each platform only does it one way (as opposed to multiple ways per-platform with `x86`)

Comment: Not pointing a finger at either side, but you'd think that after all the pain x86 calling conventions have caused, agreeing on a standard would've been a priority with x64