How to extract the definition of a macro in an external file?
I'm currently working on creating a set of random functions that I would use in future projects in C as a library (I would just need the header file and to link the lib).
Everything is working great, but I find my .h file quite unreadable, and it creates a mess in the VSCode intellisense because of the number of functions having the same base name.
For example, here's my implementation of an isPrime() function in the header file :
/** @brief Type-generic primality checker using O(sqrt(n)) algorithm */
#define isPrime(n) \
    _Generic((n), \
        u8 : isPrimeu8,  \
        u16: isPrimeu16, \
        u32: isPrimeu32, \
        u64: isPrimeu64, \
        i8 : isPrimei8,  \
        i16: isPrimei16, \
        i32: isPrimei32, \
        i64: isPrimei64, \
        default: isPrimeu64 \
    )(n)
bool isPrimeu8(u8 n);
bool isPrimeu16(u16 n);
bool isPrimeu32(u32 n);
bool isPrimeu64(u64 n);
bool isPrimei8(i8 n);
bool isPrimei16(i16 n);
bool isPrimei32(i32 n);
bool isPrimei64(i64 n);

(I use my own types that are just typedef : u -> unsigned integer, i -> signed integer, f -> floating point numbers. Then the number behind is the bits size)
As you can see, there is a lot of redundancy in the code because I want my function to be type-generic (which is a pain in C). Here's an example of my goal :
/** @brief Type-generic primality checker using O(sqrt(n)) algorithm */
#define isPrime(n) __my_function_with_all_the_type_generic_mess(n)

So, is there a way to do this? To extract the generic command in another file so that my function isPrime() still works when importing my library ?
Note : I'm currently using the latest feature of C23, so even experimental stuff is good for me, I have GCC 13.2 and will surely have GCC 14 when available.
EDIT :
Indeed, isPrime() is a bad example because it can be easily shortened by using implicit conversion on bigger type (thing that i totally forgot was possible). Here's another example which does not seem to me to be simplifiable :
/** @brief Type-generic sum on a whole array */
#define arrayAdd(array, length) \
    _Generic((array), \
        uint8_t* : arrayAddu8 , \
        uint16_t*: arrayAddu16, \
        uint32_t*: arrayAddu32, \
        uint64_t*: arrayAddu64, \
        int8_t*  : arrayAddi8 , \
        int16_t* : arrayAddi16, \
        int32_t* : arrayAddi32, \
        int64_t* : arrayAddi64, \
        float*   : arrayAddf32, \
        double*  : arrayAddf64, \
        default  : arrayAddf64  \
    )((array), (length))
uint64_t arrayAddu8 (uint8_t*  array, size_t length);
uint64_t arrayAddu16(uint16_t* array, size_t length);
uint64_t arrayAddu32(uint32_t* array, size_t length);
uint64_t arrayAddu64(uint64_t* array, size_t length);
int64_t  arrayAddi8 (int8_t*   array, size_t length);
int64_t  arrayAddi16(int16_t*  array, size_t length);
int64_t  arrayAddi32(int32_t*  array, size_t length);
int64_t  arrayAddi64(int64_t*  array, size_t length);
double   arrayAddf32(float*    array, size_t length);
double   arrayAddf64(double*   array, size_t length);

Even if the syntax can be different (for example, I don't know if I want the type-specific functions to have the same base name + type prefix form, but we can ignore that for now), I don't see a way to simplify this because the size of the type is needed for array indexation and the operations.
With all your answers, it seems there is no solution that would be as compact as templates in C++ except just trying to minimize the number of needed type-specific function by using implicit conversion and things like that. If that's

That's pretty much the way to do it.  Aside: use the types in stdint.h instead of custom types.  Aside 2: for an isPrime function, there's no reason not to have a single function that accepts an unsigned 64-bit value.

I use my own types that are just typedef ...  Immediate code review fail.

"I use my own types that are just typedef" -- this is poor practice.  C already has its own typedefs for all of those (see stdint.h).  For example, uint32_t, int64_t.  You can rely on these remaining correct if you move your code to other systems dissimilar to your current one, but not so the typedefs you write yourself.

Perhaps isPrime() is a poor example.  I don't see any reason why you need all those variants.  isPrimeu64() can handle all the unsigned cases, and all the signed cases where the value is non-negative.  I wouldn't provide any other versions, myself.

Even if you have better examples than isPrime(), I'm having trouble imagining that you have very many that actually benefit from having so many variants.  I'm inclined to guess that you're making considerably more work for yourself than you need to do.

OT: Design issue: On QWERTY keyboards, the keys u and i sit right beside each other. Your macros tuck the distinction of what might be VERY important naming information as out-of-sight as it can be... At 3:00AM, your bound to insert an unvisible big (an "invisible bug") in some tucked-away corner of code... Suggest rethink of naming these things...

@AndrewHenle No need to be pedantic about it. Not everyone works in CS and on your own projects you don't have to standardize everything.
I was inspired by Travis Vroman and his game engine video serie which made me learn a lot and he uses these exact typedef as a substitute for stdint and it works just fine (here's the playlist : link / here's the repo : link).

About your answers, @JohnBollinger and @ Fe2O3, as said in my comments to Harith answer below : using my own typedefs was an old habit that I changed because of your answers for the sake of readability and portability. Also, I'll put another answer with a better example (I hope).

I will close my question and mark this as the answer because with all the information gathered it seems it's just Impossible to do what I wanted to do.
I'll still show example of my final result because, even if it's not what I initally wanted, at least it's more readable codewise and the type-specific functions are now hidden from the intellisense of VSCode.
Don't hesitate to give me any comments if you think there is a better way.
array_functions.h :
(Note : impl_array_functions_error() is well defined)
/** @brief Type-generic function doing a operation specified by the user on a whole array. */
#define arrayDoOperation(array, length, neutral_value, operator) \
    _Generic((array), \
        uint8_t* : impl_DoOperation_uint8_t , \
        uint16_t*: impl_DoOperation_uint16_t, \
        uint32_t*: impl_DoOperation_uint32_t, \
        uint64_t*: impl_DoOperation_uint64_t, \
        int8_t*  : impl_DoOperation_int8_t  , \
        int16_t* : impl_DoOperation_int16_t , \
        int32_t* : impl_DoOperation_int32_t , \
        int64_t* : impl_DoOperation_int64_t , \
        float*   : impl_DoOperation_float   , \
        double*  : impl_DoOperation_double  , \
        default  : impl_array_functions_error \
    )((array), (length), (neutral_value), (operator))
uint64_t impl_DoOperation_uint8_t (uint8_t*  array, size_t length, uint64_t neutral_value, uint64_t (*operator)(uint64_t, uint64_t));
uint64_t impl_DoOperation_uint16_t(uint16_t* array, size_t length, uint64_t neutral_value, uint64_t (*operator)(uint64_t, uint64_t));
uint64_t impl_DoOperation_uint32_t(uint32_t* array, size_t length, uint64_t neutral_value, uint64_t (*operator)(uint64_t, uint64_t));
uint64_t impl_DoOperation_uint64_t(uint64_t* array, size_t length, uint64_t neutral_value, uint64_t (*operator)(uint64_t, uint64_t));
int64_t  impl_DoOperation_int8_t  (int8_t*   array, size_t length, int64_t  neutral_value, int64_t  (*operator)(int64_t , int64_t ));
int64_t  impl_DoOperation_int16_t (int16_t*  array, size_t length, int64_t  neutral_value, int64_t  (*operator)(int64_t , int64_t ));
int64_t  impl_DoOperation_int32_t (int32_t*  array, size_t length, int64_t  neutral_value, int64_t  (*operator)(int64_t , int64_t ));
int64_t  impl_DoOperation_int64_t (int64_t*  array, size_t length, int64_t  neutral_value, int64_t  (*operator)(int64_t , int64_t ));
double   impl_DoOperation_float   (float*    array, size_t length, double   neutral_value, double   (*operator)(double  , double  ));
double   impl_DoOperation_double  (double*   array, size_t length, double   neutral_value, double   (*operator)(double  , double  ));

array_functions/arrayDoOperation.c
(Note : the header file is in completely different directory because it's like a public api, the first file is what is what you should include and the "array_functions" folder is where there is all my implementations)
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>



#define GEN_FUNC_ARRAY_DO_OPERATION_UNSIGNED(bitsize) \
uint64_t impl_DoOperation_uint##bitsize##_t(uint##bitsize##_t* array, size_t length, uint64_t neutral_value, uint64_t (*operator)(uint64_t, uint64_t)) { \
    uint64_t retval = neutral_value;                \
                                                    \
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i) {         \
        retval = (*operator)(retval, array[i]);     \
    }                                               \
                                                    \
    return retval;                                  \
}

GEN_FUNC_ARRAY_DO_OPERATION_UNSIGNED(8)
GEN_FUNC_ARRAY_DO_OPERATION_UNSIGNED(16)
GEN_FUNC_ARRAY_DO_OPERATION_UNSIGNED(32)
GEN_FUNC_ARRAY_DO_OPERATION_UNSIGNED(64)


#define GEN_FUNC_ARRAY_DO_OPERATION_SIGNED(bitsize) \
int64_t impl_DoOperation_int##bitsize##_t(int##bitsize##_t* array, size_t length, int64_t neutral_value, int64_t (*operator)(int64_t, int64_t)) { \
    int64_t retval = neutral_value;                 \
                                                    \
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i) {         \
        retval = (*operator)(retval, array[i]);     \
    }                                               \
                                                    \
    return retval;                                  \
}

GEN_FUNC_ARRAY_DO_OPERATION_SIGNED(8)
GEN_FUNC_ARRAY_DO_OPERATION_SIGNED(16)
GEN_FUNC_ARRAY_DO_OPERATION_SIGNED(32)
GEN_FUNC_ARRAY_DO_OPERATION_SIGNED(64)


#define GEN_FUNC_ARRAY_DO_OPERATION_FLOAT(type_name) \
double impl_DoOperation_##type_name(type_name* array, size_t length, double neutral_value, double (*operator)(double, double)) { \
    double retval = neutral_value;                  \
                                                    \
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i) {         \
        retval = (*operator)(retval, array[i]);     \
    }                                               \
                                                    \
    return retval;                                  \
}

GEN_FUNC_ARRAY_DO_OPERATION_FLOAT(float)
GEN_FUNC_ARRAY_DO_OPERATION_FLOAT(double)


If the sole problem is with VSCode intellisense, just change the base name.
Apart from that, if you're defining them all separately, and the problem is code duplication, one simplification would be to generate them with a macro:
#define gen_isprime(type) \
     bool isPrime##type(type n) { \
         // Add the code here     \
     } \

// And now:

gen_isprime(u8)
gen_isprime(u16)
gen_isprime(u32)
gen_isprime(u64)
gen_isprime(i8)
gen_isprime(i16)
gen_isprime(i32)
gen_isprime(i64)

Though I don't see why you can't have just two isPrimeu64() and isPrimei64() functions, or not use the types from stdint.h (uint64_t, int32_t et cetera).

I already tried to change the base name, the simple fact that the name is contained it (for exemple i tried doing "__isPrimeu8" or "__nc_llb__isPrimeu8" and it did not really change anything)

And i'm just playing with the generics stuff in C so it's not really the most optimal thing to do indeed... but if there is no other way then shall be it x)
And I know stdint.h but i found these types too "verbose" or long so that's why i wanted to create my own, but for the sake of portability and readbility i think it's time to change my habits

@lordeji Why not just do away with one for unsigned 64 bits and signed 64 bits?. Those would work for all types with less bits.

@lordeji The names are internal to your library, and not something that would be called by the clients. So just choose a completely different name? As of leading underscores, those are reserved for the implementation.

Implicit conversion in functions is not considered bad practice ??? If not, i've been fooled my whole life

@lordeji https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711588/passing-uint8-t-instead-of-uint32-t-into-a-function-in-c
